# Netlogo scale-color with varying values

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo I'm using scale-color with the following line:

```
ask patches [set pcolor scale-color green potential min-potential max-potential]
```

Potential is a patch variable that is always changing. The question is: how can I get the minimum and maximum value of this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would simply be:

```
let min-potential min [ potential ] of patches
let max-potential max [ potential ] of patches
```

I suggest storing them in local variables before your `ask` block so that they don't have to be recalculated each time a patch performs the `set pcolor ...` operation.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, it worked. Will also do your local variable suggestion.